# Javascript Plugins in Angular Do not show up, but HTML is there

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nouislider

I'm trying to use a few different javascript libraries for a rangeslider. However, for each one I use, I do not see anything in the browser - even though I can see the HTML being generated. I have settled on using nouislider.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, OnInit, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as nouislider from 'nouislider';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<div #here></div>',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('here') range : ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    nouislider.create(this.range.nativeElement,
      {
        start: [20, 80],
        connect: true,
        range: {
          'min': 0,
          'max': 100
        }
    });
  }
}
```

And the result:
[image]

Is there something I am missing? This is an empty Angular 4 project. I know there are directives for nouislider which are already made. However I have also not been able to get them to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do not see anything in the browser - even though I can see the HTML being generated

Did you include the CSS?